# Content is Not Allowed in Prolog in res images

Tags: android, android-studio

I have read others SO answers but i cant figure it out...please help me.
 When i tired to copy my splash screen images to res folder...after copying files i am getting this errors

```
home/nteam/OrderliteProject/Orderlite/app/src/main/res/xxxhdpi/sp_bg.png
Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
/home/nteam/OrderliteProject/Orderlite/app/src/main/res/hdpi/sp_bg.png
Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
/home/nteam/OrderliteProject/Orderlite/app/src/main/res/xxhdpi/sp_bg.png
Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
/home/nteam/OrderliteProject/Orderlite/app/src/main/res/mdpi/sp_bg.png
Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
/home/nteam/OrderliteProject/Orderlite/app/src/main/res/ldpi/sp_bg.png
Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
/home/nteam/OrderliteProject/Orderlite/app/src/main/res/xhdpi/sp_bg.png
Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
```

I also tried to delete these images and try to recompile it but i steel get the same error. Please help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have invalid directory names in `/res`. The valid directory names for `Drawable` Resources start with `drawable-`. For example, `drawable-xxxhdpi`, `drawable-xxhdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`, etc.

Comment: In case it helps someone else: I had a similar problem where some directories had found there way into `/res` named with underscores instead of dashes, e.g. `drawable_xxxhdpi` instead of `drawable-xxxhdpi`